# Trying to figure out For Loops

Tags: r, holtwinters

I'm just trying to get the For loop to increment a rolling window with a 1 month increment and determine the HW parameters at each increment.

```
ss<-c(29,36,36,48,93,28,35,28,37,50,37,3,25,28,40,45,38,43,34,44,43,25,33,34)
ss2<-t(ss)
for (i in 1:12){
sseries<-ts(ss2[c(i:11+i)],frequency=12)
ssforecasts <- HoltWinters(sseries, beta=FALSE, gamma=FALSE)
ssforecasts
}
```

But I get :

> Error in ts(cbind(xhat = final.fit$level[-len - 1], level = final.fit$level[-len -  : 
>     'ts' object must have one or more observations

Comment: Try having some `cat` commands in your for loop so that you have a better idea of what is happening and what is causing the error.  For example, `for (i in 1:12){
  sseries <- ts(ss2[c(i:11+i)],frequency=12)
  cat(paste0("Information for Series ",i,"\n"))
  cat(sseries)
  cat("\n")
  ssforecasts <- HoltWinters(sseries, beta=FALSE, gamma=FALSE)
  print(ssforecasts)
  cat("\n")
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling a slice properly, but R's order of evaluation is not evaluating as you seem to want it to. When you get to `i=11` you get this:

```
> i:11+i
[1] 22
```

which is what is giving the error, try this instead:

```
ss<-c(29,36,36,48,93,28,35,28,37,50,37,3,25,28,40,45,38,43,34,44,43,25,33,34)
ss2<-t(ss)
for (i in 1:12){
  sseries<-ts(ss2[c(i:(11+i))],frequency=12)
  ssforecasts <- HoltWinters(sseries, beta=FALSE, gamma=FALSE)
  ssforecasts
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that the parameters should be printed out, but it wants a continuation.

Comment: try adding a `print()` statement within the loop

Answer (score 0):

OK, I had to use the statement print(ssforecasts) to get the results.